# Content Carousel for jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am developing a mobile app using jquery mobile. I am looking to implement a "tips" section. A tip will be visible on the screen, and with a side swipe, I would like to view another tip.

I was under the impression JQM would have a simple carousel type widget... that can be loaded with html content. That does not seem to be the case.

P.S. I am not looking for an image slider specifically, I want to slide and randomize a carousel that can be loaded with html elements (text).

Anyone have some ideas on what plays well with jquery mobile for mobile apps? (Cordova)

Comment: Owl Carousel would probably work for you: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Flex-slider and served me quite well.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CPpBD/)

[Product link](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)

Initialization:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlsContainer: ".flex-container"
            });
        });
```

Markup

```
<!-- slider -->
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="slides/1.jpg" alt="slide">
                    <p class="flex-caption">Awesomeness</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="slides/2.jpg" alt="slide">
                    <p class="flex-caption"> &laquo;Fantastic &raquo;</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="slides/3.jpg" alt="slide"> 
                    <p class="flex-caption"> &laquo; Wow &raquo;</p>                        
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did the job, thanks for the effort with the implementation. The NAV buttons messed my around a bit, but I see that happens to many a folk :-)